# regex replace or add text to URL

Tags: regex, url, replace, addition

Recently we had a problem with servers and we had to change our paths.
We have like 1000 auctions on ebay and changing links to images one by one would be just stupid.

I`m trying to write a regex that would find all links (already done that), and the next part looks like this:

`www.mysite.com/statics/some_image.jpg`
and I would want it to look like this:
`www.mysite.com/uploads/statics/some_image.jpg`
so the thing is to add `uploads` to that link.

Comment: What flavor = language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?\/)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1uploads/`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD0sJ3/6

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(.*?\/)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "www.mysite.com/statics/some_image.jpg"
subst = "\1uploads/"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: This finds me a text but how can I add a new text ?

Comment: This is the reason why you should tell us what language are you using?

Comment: Oh I`m sorry...Im using python